# Android EditText don't stick to keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing a form on Android.
I have a set of questions and some can be answered with free text. for those I use an editText, which is contained in a larger container, which itself is contained in a scrollview with its siblings.

When the editText is focused, the scrollview scrolls to be sure the edittext is visible, but I want to see the full container view.

Below some paint drawings to show what I mean :

When the editText is focused, I have this :

[image]

But I want this :

[image]

I can't find a way to achieve this. Does anybody have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in ScrollView. Use ScrollView after  Parent Layout. Then Put All Containers in LinearLayout . So the LinearLayout will be inclosed in ScrollView. it will work. if you do not understand then share the code.  I will fix that in seconds.